# Pac4j based SP unable to process SAML response - Signature is not trusted

Tags: playframework-2.0, saml-2.0, shibboleth

I am developing a play application using pac4j for SAML authentication. I have already setup a shibboleth based IDP and it is working fine with a couple of SPs.
I have based the play application on the pac4j demo, which works fine with openidp-feide, but is failing against my shibboleth IDP.
I have generated the keystore as per instructions and have also configured the IDP metadata in the application. The request goes fine and i am prompted with the authentication page. Once i enter the credentials and the response comes back to the play application, things go wrong.
The error message that i get is as follows

```
[debug] - org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference - Verification successful for URI "#_3b44b10eeb4a12dcf2abfe318a01885e" 
[debug] - org.apache.xml.security.signature.Manifest - The Reference has Type 
[debug] - org.opensaml.xmlsec.signature.support.provider.ApacheSantuarioSignatureValidationProviderImpl
- Signature validated with key from supplied credential [debug] - org.opensaml.xmlsec.signature.support.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine - Signature validation using candidate credential was successful [debug]
- org.opensaml.xmlsec.signature.support.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine - Successfully verified signature using KeyInfo-derived credential 
[debug] - org.opensaml.xmlsec.signature.support.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine - Attempting to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential 
[debug] - org.opensaml.xmlsec.signature.support.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine - Failed to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential 
[debug] - org.opensaml.xmlsec.signature.support.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine - Failed to verify signature and/or establish trust using any KeyInfo-derived credentials [debug] - org.opensaml.xmlsec.signature.support.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine
- Attempting to verify signature using trusted credentials [debug] - org.opensaml.xmlsec.signature.support.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine
- Failed to verify signature using either KeyInfo-derived or directly trusted credentials 
[error] - play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Cannot invoke the action org.pac4j.saml.exceptions.SAMLException: Signature is not trusted
    at 
    org.pac4j.saml.sso.impl.SAML2DefaultResponseValidator.validateSignature(SAML2DefaultResponseValidator.java:690) ~[pac4j-saml-1.8.3.jar:na]
    at org.pac4j.saml.sso.impl.SAML2DefaultResponseValidator.validateSamlProtocolResponse(SAML2DefaultResponseValidator.java:206) ~[pac4j-saml-1.8.3.jar:na]
    at org.pac4j.saml.sso.impl.SAML2DefaultResponseValidator.validate(SAML2DefaultResponseValidator.java:144) ~[pac4j-saml-1.8.3.jar:na]
    at org.pac4j.saml.sso.impl.SAML2WebSSOMessageReceiver.receiveMessage(SAML2WebSSOMessageReceiver.java:96) ~[pac4j-saml-1.8.3.jar:na]
    at org.pac4j.saml.sso.impl.SAML2WebSSOProfileHandler.receive(SAML2WebSSOProfileHandler.java:55) ~[pac4j-saml-1.8.3.jar:na]
    at org.pac4j.saml.client.SAML2Client.retrieveCredentials(SAML2Client.java:246) ~[pac4j-saml-1.8.3.jar:na]
    at org.pac4j.saml.client.SAML2Client.retrieveCredentials(SAML2Client.java:75) ~[pac4j-saml-1.8.3.jar:na]
    at org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.getCredentials(IndirectClient.java:191) ~[pac4j-core-1.8.3.jar:na]
```

I have checked against the response that shibboleth is sending and its clear that the same certifcate that has been configured in the SP metadata is being used for signing. I have also checked that the signing certificate of IDP is same as the one provided in the IDP metadata

The SAML Response at shibboleth is as below

```
2016-01-24 23:47:12,017 - DEBUG [org.opensaml.saml.saml2.binding.encoding.impl.HTTPPostEncoder:198] - Marshalling and Base64 encoding SAML message
2016-01-24 23:47:12,024 - DEBUG [org.opensaml.saml.saml2.binding.encoding.impl.HTTPPostEncoder:220] - Setting RelayState parameter to: 'myappidp', encoded as 'myappidp'
2016-01-24 23:47:12,040 - DEBUG [PROTOCOL_MESSAGE:70] -
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:Response
    Destination="http://lms.myapp.in/auth/complete/tpa-saml/"
    ID="_51e20c09b33474416b337650cea49879"
    InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_3873668f77ebeefc8e0f4011223f8877d98b17db"
    IssueInstant="2016-01-24T18:17:11.804Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://idp.myapp.in/idp/shibboleth</saml2:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature
                xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod
                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod
                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
<ds:Reference
                        URI="#_51e20c09b33474416b337650cea49879">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform
                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<ds:Transform
                    Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>nuS/WnS4LarO4u0tcLy99kbZwXVk9RG/fD8ooZi/Mbs=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>
kaESN6JGaUfMs1SbAr1BsmJCD/2kddZFCarJcO1jmULQJHrqfRkBrnaqQeFT129+jKXqksxSdv0C
nSENGWDVJS+A2KCJn7MzJdMjUTokJEf6M76dKycYD9/W0zQFKG6FFcCUReeH/GZm9iezCyP9C4Wc
qpeaC+2po61TTQ82OtGh3pIvZ2bUcDmbU/UWBbUX1EJv7twvCayW5+jlIfIWjZjpt73PqtvwMxht
IT9vwcme5i6NYZTxYlJ9w2wvIFLXInLOM73pD+TG4eEZtONeztW+BGgGZ5McJdpPMnkiNouOo+WA
B77yGBq8w+ubIIlxPU5ASv5r/YqxOPJyZZIhEw==
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDMzCCAhugAwIBAgIUf9lIsNpjiw9W3K/sv9ZtXwDb5PkwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwHDEaMBgG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</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </saml2p:Status>
    <saml2:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <xenc:EncryptedData Id="_53e9ea4d7ce2e06dd7dc5f447e03f248"
            Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod
                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"/>
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <xenc:EncryptedKey
                    Id="_1f15b021e3b9352a57cc33a7ef00626e"
                    Recipient="http://lms.myapp.in/saml" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <xenc:EncryptionMethod
                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                        <ds:DigestMethod
                            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
                    </xenc:EncryptionMethod>
                    <ds:KeyInfo>
                        <ds:X509Data>
                            <ds:X509Certificate>MIIEBzCCAu+gAwIBAgIJAKFBsY8ExEytMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGZMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJTjEL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</ds:X509Certificate>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                    </ds:KeyInfo>
                    <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                        <xenc:CipherValue>Ewo8Qu6Wq/rDo06DoiiTkyIx8FJTio1gltDg1rz9x+R6hHkXuJKJupTHF4Idk2K3CoF8uwFPDPNp
f95/EOzYfWAVMI8VDH1hv8DCez+ArKLIcqYywgZc2zRk4ZETSLkIznzemqF8fiCpD/F+jQhFz0xX
o5YA0jkOUel25iW7+3VvPOWwXmJBZrZn3kmTmoM3wiC5DQQnkOoJJFDUNLSax8ptKn8CiQfQeiG1
/2EyTBIW+EKvrahCVjyE8k5sbeXlRY3YIsX8ep0tY9QbMEZkyOD4E4DNpXJqsNBBsEsrpW6+nnQJ
3Chx8ofq1eAWeT+bVa+fLkx2BiNWrQicEhfDPg==</xenc:CipherValue>
                    </xenc:CipherData>
                </xenc:EncryptedKey>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <xenc:CipherValue>ad2hJpuF+fEwR0CjvpZkNvOhk5jvEjz55UvpeUWyBHxVLK2Loo2GvUCTZIOmQMNfcovK19BPAjZd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</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </saml2:EncryptedAssertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

While the SAML response being received at Play is as below

```
[debug] - org.apache.xml.security.signature.Manifest - verify 1 References
[debug] - org.apache.xml.security.signature.Manifest - I am not requested to follow nested Manifests
[debug] - org.apache.xml.security.utils.ElementProxy - setElement("ds:Reference", "")
[debug] - org.apache.xml.security.utils.ElementProxy - setElement("ds:Transforms", "")
[debug] - org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.JCEMapper - Request for URI http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512
[debug] - org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver - I was asked to create a ResourceResolver and got 0
[debug] - org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver - check resolvability by class org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver
[debug] - org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.implementations.ResolverFragment - State I can resolve reference: "#_3b44b10eeb4a12dcf2abfe318a01885e"
[debug] - org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.implementations.ResolverFragment - Try to catch an Element with ID _3b44b10eeb4a12dcf2abfe318a01885e and Element was [saml2p:Response: null]
[debug] - org.apache.xml.security.utils.ElementProxy - setElement("ds:Transform", "")
[debug] - org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transforms - Perform the (0)th http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature transform
[debug] - org.apache.xml.security.utils.ElementProxy - setElement("ds:Transform", "")
[debug] - org.apache.xml.security.utils.DigesterOutputStream - Pre-digested input:
[debug] - org.apache.xml.security.utils.DigesterOutputStream - <saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="http://portal.myapp.in/callback?client_name=SAML2Client" ID="_3b44b10eeb4a12dcf2abfe318a01885e" InResponseTo="_ryoorwhqkqx08jkedtd54lx4ar5ebfgwryqn5bz" IssueInstant="2016-01-24T18:16:25.262Z" Version="2.0"><saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://idp.myapp.in/idp/shibboleth</saml2:Issuer><saml2p:Status><saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"></saml2p:StatusCode></saml2p:Status><saml2:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"><xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="_1d9472da7abbc00140a313b15b4a6874" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"></xenc:EncryptionMethod><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><xenc:EncryptedKey Id="_d87aeb230d3dc2281f31f0ad9df7bfee" Recipient="http://portal.myapp.in/saml"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod></xenc:EncryptionMethod><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIIDhjCCAm6gAwIBAgIEVqTnkzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBhDELMAkGA1UEBhMCSU4xCzAJBgNV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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>LjiZaaGgldyQS4AJ3y2sJbbnQHF+4epKHQ9kUiGdOphITxClArrqpSUXO+9DlQnhfLLhvfk+yBkg
OyTkMhTq+UA9oTKTGLDRkwwAnhRiaILfIW3ajTMXsfE0SBJFBnhoWERyk0EMppPa+2Q3d+ErxJGS
0RA14nOfweNtX8S/Utl1uwoewFnIjobSVxHbwQB3ARxK92nXfJnRNEDaAVp73MPkhib9n51GlVNt
yjyqN+YuM1MHbfxZxN7KMvtcborhCz2oyhfq9ZSVkJA0nO+mSWZkiuF0fBG2TwrbABd/zecTTy/U
lGUR4AkqpFfuMvL3KouOrJHVrQ4ipZGw8BA7oQ==</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedKey></ds:KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>zW0B1jmTWtbx6GDm/l6hzErGhDDE+I9tnsWIWjvlmsIw2s9lbEji/+BAJs7WN1pIfds06oIPT+1A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=</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedData></saml2:EncryptedAssertion></saml2p:Response>
```

Really not sure what i am doing wrong here. Appreciate any help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the IdP's certificate into your keystore. `keytool` should ask you if you want to trust the certificate, to which you'll answer 'yes' (after visually verifying the fingerprints, of course).

The certificate is also in the IdP metadata XML file you should have (they should match).

Comment: I had abandoned the approach and went a different way. Will try this out again and respond. Thanks.

Comment: @JerryK please repond with the solutions which worked for you !